# Create a visit counter for every new user using session

Tags: java, session, servlets

Create a webapplication that displays, A client page contains username and button .On submittion of page if user visits for first time then display Message “Welcome” If user visit for second time then display message “WelcomeBack ” “This is your Visitno:“

Comment: What is your question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was able to create a session and start the counter but whenever a different user logs in it continues the previous user counter instead of starting a counter from 1